# How to track an opened hand in any environment with RGB camera?

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine

I want to make a movable camera that tracks an opened hand (toward the floor). It just needs to track the opened hand but it has to also know the rotation (2d rotation).

This is what I searched for so far:

- **Contour**- As the camera is movable, the background is unknown, even the lighting is not fixed. It's hard for me to get a clear hand
  segment in real time.
- **Haar**- It seems this just returns a rect and can't deal with rotation.
- **Feature detect**- A hand doesn't have enough detail for this.

I am using the Opencv Unity plugin to do this.

*EDIT*
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826377/Rapid-Object-Detection-in-Csharp

I see another library can do something like this. Can OpenCV also do this?

Comment: Have you tried HSV based skin detection ? Please share some sample images of the background that you're working with

Comment: i can't share image. but the problem is i can't make it good. I am doing it with YUV but there are always noise. And i can't find a good way automatically adjust the value correctly

Comment: try HSV instead. It'll help you with the skin coloured surfaces